# How to do a series of validations in Elixir the most idiomatic way

Tags: elixir

I am new (but curious) to Elixir. I want to validate two aspects of an URL :

- it should not be an IP adress
- the path should not contains `/../`

I have a function:

```
def validate_url(url) do
  URI.parse(url)
  |> validate_profile
end
```

After some pattern matching (to exclude other cases), I come to 2 (unstatisfying) solutions :

1st :

```
defp validate_profile(%URI{scheme: "https", path: path, host: host, userinfo: nil, fragment: nil}),
     do: validate_path(path)
         |> validate_host(host)
<snip code>
defp validate_profile(_), do: :invalid

defp validate_path(path) do
  case String.split(path, ["/../"]) do
    [_ | []] -> :valid
    _ -> :invalid
  end
end

defp validate_host(:invalid, _), do: :invalid
defp validate_host(:valid, host) do
  case :inet.parse_address(to_charlist(host)) do
    {:ok, _} -> :invalid
    _ -> :valid
  end
end
```

2nd:

```
defp validate_profile(%URI{scheme: "https", path: path, host: host, userinfo: nil, fragment: nil}),
     do: validate_path(path, host)
         |> validate_host
<snip code>
defp validate_profile(_), do: :invalid

defp validate_path(path, host) do
  case String.split(path, ["/../"]) do
    [_ | []] -> host
    _ -> :invalid
  end
end

defp validate_host(:invalid), do: :invalid
defp validate_host(host) do
  case :inet.parse_address(to_charlist(host)) do
    {:ok, _} -> :invalid
    _ -> :valid
  end
end
```

How can I improve here ? Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to make the validations more chainable and return detailed error information.

```
defmodule Validate do
  def valid_url?(url) do
    validate_url(url) == :ok
  end

  def validate_url(url) when is_binary(url) do
    url
    |> URI.parse()
    |> validate_url
  end

  def validate_url(%URI{path: nil}), do: {:error, :no_path_info}
  def validate_url(%URI{host: nil}), do: {:error, :no_host_info}

  def validate_url(%URI{scheme: "https", path: path, host: host}) do
    with :ok <- validate_path(path), # You can add more validations here
         :ok <- validate_host(host) do
      :ok
    else
      error -> error
    end
  end

  def validate_url(_), do: {:error, :other_error}

  defp validate_path(path) do
    if String.contains?(path, "/../") do
      {:error, :path_cannot_contain_parent_reference}
    else
      :ok
    end
  end

  defp validate_host(host) do
    case :inet.parse_address(to_charlist(host)) do
      {:ok, _} -> {:error, :host_cannot_be_ip_address}
      _ -> :ok
    end
  end
end
```

And some tests:

```
defmodule ValidateTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "validate_url" do
    assert Validate.validate_url("https://example.com/bar/123") == :ok
    assert Validate.validate_url("https://example.com/bar/123/../456") == {:error, :path_cannot_contain_parent_reference}
    assert Validate.validate_url("1.2.3.4") == {:error, :no_host_info}
    assert Validate.validate_url("https://1.2.3.4") == {:error, :no_path_info}
    assert Validate.validate_url("http://1.2.3.4") == {:error, :no_path_info}
    assert Validate.validate_url("http://example.com/bar/123") == {:error, :other_error}
    assert Validate.validate_url(123) == {:error, :other_error}
  end

  test "valid_url?" do
    assert Validate.valid_url?("https://example.com/bar/123")
    refute Validate.valid_url?("https://example.com/bar/123/../456")
  end
end
```

Comment: I will try with the `with` keyword, thank you (and yes, I have unit test I didn't provide here)

Comment: Swapping blacklisting to whitelisting is _never_ a good idea. `:inet.parse_address('256.256.256.256') #⇒ {:error, :einval}`.

Comment: I just want to reject all IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

Blindly treating anything that returned an `:error` from some method as success is never a good idea. One might go with somewhat like splitting the host part by dots *and* validating the last part is a valid top-level domain.

```rb
host
|> String.split('.')
|> Enum.reverse()
|> hd()
|> Kernel.in(@allowed_domains)
```

or, maybe easier, check if the last block of codepoints contains at least one letter, not digit.